# JOI validation to validare object from a given array of objects

Tags: joi

My request body contains a Javascript/JSON object:

```js
{ id: 1, value: "example 1"}
```

I have an list of allowed objects:

```js
[
  { id: 1, value: "example 1" } ,
  { id: 2, value: "example 2" } ,
  { id: 3, value: "example 3" } ,
]
```

I am writing a [Joi schema](https://joi.dev/) and would like to validate that the object in the request body is in my list of allowed values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Joi's `any.custom()` property: https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.2.1#anycustommethod-description. You would need a function along the lines of

```js
const _ = require('lodash');

const allowed = [
  { id: 1, value: 'value 1' } ,
  ...
  { id: 9, value: 'value 9' },
];

function isOneOf(allowedValues) {
  return (v, helpers) => {
    if ( ! _.some(allowedValues, x => _.isEqual(x,v) ) {
      return helpers.error('naughty!');
    }
  };
}
```

which you should be able use along the lines of:

```js
...any().custom( isOneOf(allowedValues) );
```

Answer (score -1):

i am assuming the id in the array unique

```
yourObj = {id:1,value: "example 1"};

yourArray = [{id:1,value: "example 1"},{id:2,value: "example 2"},{id:3,value: "example 3"}]

isObjectAvailable = yourArray.some(el=>el.id===yourObj.id)
console.log(isObjectAvailable) // return true if found else false
```

Comment: so you mean i need to add custom validation?

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you want your schema to validate this array of objects.

```
const example = {
      "id": 1,
      "value": "example1"
   };
```

Joi schema should be

```
var validator = require('@hapi/joi');

const rules = validator.object().keys({
        id: validator.number().required(),
        value: validator.string().required()
    })
```

Comment: no, the object must  be present in the given array to pass validation